# Why does returning a floating-point value change its value?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, x86

The following code raises the `assert` on Red Hat 5.4 32 bits but works on Red Hat 5.4 64 bits (or CentOS).

On 32 bits, I must put the return value of `millis2seconds` in a variable, otherwise the `assert` is raised, showing that the value of the `double` returned from the function is different from the one that was passed to it.

If you comment the "#define BUG" line, it works.

Thanks to @R, passing the -msse2 -mfpmath options to the compiler make both variants of the millis2seconds function work.

```
/*
 * TestDouble.cpp
 */

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static double millis2seconds(int millis) {
#define BUG
#ifdef BUG
    // following is not working on 32 bits architectures for any values of millis
    // on 64 bits architecture, it works
    return (double)(millis) / 1000.0;
#else
    //  on 32 bits architectures, we must do the operation in 2 steps ?!? ...
    // 1- compute a result in a local variable, and 2- return the local variable
    // why? somebody can explains?
    double result = (double)(millis) / 1000.0;
    return result;
#endif
}

static void testMillis2seconds() {
    int millis = 10;
    double seconds = millis2seconds(millis);

    printf("millis                  : %d\n", millis);
    printf("seconds                 : %f\n", seconds);
    printf("millis2seconds(millis)  : %f\n", millis2seconds(millis));
    printf("seconds <  millis2seconds(millis)  : %d\n", seconds < millis2seconds(millis));
    printf("seconds >  millis2seconds(millis)  : %d\n", seconds > millis2seconds(millis));
    printf("seconds == millis2seconds(millis)  : %d\n", seconds == millis2seconds(millis));

    assert(seconds == millis2seconds(millis));
}

extern int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    testMillis2seconds();
}
```

Comment: I guess it's the compiler spilling registers. try  `__attribute__ ((noinline))` maybe?

Comment: No, it's excess precision.

Comment: Never, never, *never*, **never** compare floating point values for equality.  The variable forces the value to be truncated from 80 to 64 bit precision.  Usually.

Comment: @HansPassant: There are plenty of occasions where comparing floating point values for equality is exactly the right thing to do. Including here: OP is trying to understand where the unexpected result is coming from.

Comment: @HansPassant that's because the spilling, isn't it?

Comment: You know a 64-bit int will not fit in a double without dropping some bits right?

Comment: @R.., apart from possibly comparing a floating point value with 0.0, I cannot think of any situations where comparing for equality is appropriate. What did you have in mind?

Comment: Any time you are working with an exact result, or where you're guaranteed a correctly-rounded result.

Comment: @microtherion: `1.0` can always be represented exactly, as can many other values. There are computations that mathematically yield `1.0` that don't necessarily do so in floating-point (`1.0 / 3.0 * 3.0`, for example), but this: `double d = 1.0; if (d == 1.0) ...` should always work reliably.

Comment: @microtherion There are also many times when you want to perform a comparison and neither value was the result of an expression evaluation. Say you set a variable to a default value of `360.0`. Then later you want to check if the value is different from that default. In that situation you would write `x != 360.0`.

Comment: the point is that I wrote: seconds = millis2seconds(millis);
and assert(seconds == millis2seconds(millis)) should be OK no?
why computing twice millis2seconds will returns 2 different values ?

Comment: @armandbendanan The short answer is that the C++ standard doesn't insist that they have the same value.  The longer answer is that `double seconds = millis2seconds(millis)` probably got turned into a 64 bit value, while the call to `millis2seconds(millis)` was probably turned into an 80+ bit value, and when compared to the 64 bit value it did not compare equal.  The short answer is, don't compare `double`s with equality and expect it to behave like a real number.

Comment: @DavieHeffernan And when someone changes the default value to `360.1`, and does the same at the other end, it starts working or not working based on extremely brittle compiler decisions.  Instead of using a flag value to determine if the value is different than the default, why not actually track if the value was changed from the default?  If the value could be changed by user input, examine the user input (maybe after converting to a fixed-point decimal) instead of the brittle `double` that you turn the user input into.

Comment: *never, never, never* has the dogmatic recommendation of not comparing floats for equality been appropriate for all cases. Often comparing for equality is exactly the right thing to do. But judging from the vote counts on your and *R..*'s comments the balance still seems to be in favor of the floating-point-aware people.

Comment: @Yakk Literals have the precision of their types. `360.1` in a program represents the `double` nearest to this number, and does so everywhere. One can compare two variables separately set to this value, or compare one variable set to this value and the floating-point literal, and expect the comparison to do what it should. I have never had anyone complain that the answers of test at http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2011/11/08/Floating-point-quiz differed from what their compiler did.

Comment: I wonder, why would one store seconds as double? For computational use I would use the smallest resolution possible on a particular machine. And for human readable representation, displaying 0.42327561 would make more fuss than clarity. (Sorry, it was not the question, But being a project manager, I would fire programmers involved in such long discussions, caused by "invented" problems :-)

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz, what if the resolution changes downwards?

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz, date / time have a lot of representations: struct timeval, struct timespec, and others which do not compare well. I convert everything in a double value to facilitate comparaisons and I have obviously functions / methods to display them and to convert back to struct timeval, struct timespec.
Forget the time / millis / seconds choice using double value, the problem here is that setting a double variable x from a function f which return a double value: x=f(), the test: x == f() should return true no? It doesn't. This is my point.

Comment: I've upvoted BOTH the never compare floating point values comment AND the one saying that sometimes it's valid. Because NEVER compare floating point values for equality is good default advice but if you understand why sometimes you can and should then you probably know enough to understand when it's appropriate.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

With the cdecl calling convention, which is used on Linux x86 systems, a double is returned from a function using the st0 x87 register.  All x87 registers are 80-bit precision.  With this code:

```
static double millis2seconds(int millis) {
    return (double)(millis) / 1000.0;
};
```

The compiler calculates the division using 80-bit precision.  When gcc is using the GNU dialect of the standard (which it does by default), it leaves the result in the st0 register, so the full precision is returned back to the caller.  The end of the assembly code looks like this:

```
fdivrp  %st, %st(1)  # Divide st0 by st1 and store the result in st0
leave
ret                  # Return
```

With this code,

```
static double millis2seconds(int millis) {
    double result = (double)(millis) / 1000.0;
    return result;
}
```

the result is stored into a 64-bit memory location, which loses some precision.  The 64-bit value is loaded back into the 80-bit st0 register before returning, but the damage is already done:

```
fdivrp  %st, %st(1)   # Divide st0 by st1 and store the result in st0
fstpl   -8(%ebp)      # Store st0 onto the stack
fldl    -8(%ebp)      # Load st0 back from the stack
leave
ret                   # Return
```

In your main, the first result is stored in a 64-bit memory location, so the extra precision is lost either way:

```
double seconds = millis2seconds(millis);
```

but in the second call, the return value is used directly, so the compiler can keep it in a register:

```
assert(seconds == millis2seconds(millis));
```

When using the first version of `millis2seconds`, you end up comparing the value that has been truncated to 64-bit precision to the value with full 80-bit precision, so there is a difference.

On x86-64, calculations are done using SSE registers, which are only 64-bit, so this issue doesn't come up.

Also, if you use `-std=c99` so that you don't get the GNU dialect, the calculated values are stored in memory and re-loaded into the register before returning so as to be standard-conforming.

Comment: Thanks very very mush for your clear explanation.
This is exactly what I was missing.
But now, why on 64 bit architectures, both versions of millis2seconds are working?

Comment: @armandbendanan: because on 64-bit, it returns double values in an xmm register as 64 bits, rather than in an 80-bit x87 register.

Comment: I find this surprising because IEC 9899:201x says "If the return expression is evaluated in a floating-point format different from the return type, the expression is converted as if by assignment [which removes any extra range and precision] to the return type of the function and the resulting value is returned to the caller."

Comment: ... but, I see that text is not in ISO/IEC 9899:TC2, the current actual standard.

Comment: This answer is not correct with respect to the C language. Use `-std=c99`. GCC is probably non-conforming by default.

Comment: @poolie: yes, that's a good point.  gcc is not standard-conforming in this respect by default since it uses the GNU dialect.  I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Actually, [I looked in to it more](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16888666/243712) and it I think gcc does comply with the current standard, just not the current draft (which is fair enough.)

Comment: @poolie: That's no longer just a draft. It's C11.

Comment: @poolie: That's interesting, since using `-std=c99` makes it truncate as well.

Answer (score 8):

On i386 (32-bit x86), all floating point expressions are evaluated as an 80-bit IEEE-extended floating point type. This is reflected in `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`, from float.h, being defined as 2. Storing the result to a variable or applying a cast to the result drops the excess precision via rounding, but that's still not sufficient to guarantee the same result you would see on an implementation (like x86_64) without excess precision, since rounding twice can give different results than performing a computation and rounding in the same step.

One way around this problem is to build using SSE math even on x86 targets, with `-msse2 -mfpmath=sse`.

Comment: Just tried to add those flags to the compiler but same results

Comment: Are you sure you added them correctly? Using them should give identical behavior to what you see on x86_64.

Comment: heu, don't know, here is my command line:
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -msse -mfpmath=sse -MMD -MP -MF"TestDouble.d" -MT"TestDouble.d" -o "TestDouble.o" "../TestDouble.cpp"

Comment: `-msse` is not `-msse2`. Fix that and try again.

Comment: @R, yes, you are right, I was missing the '2'. Using -msse2 -mfpmath=sse, it works. I will update my question (answer).

Answer (score 4):

It's worth noting first of all that since the function is implicitly pure and called twice with a constant argument the compiler would be within its rights to elide the computation and the comparison altogether.

clang-3.0-6ubuntu3 does eliminate the pure function call with -O9, and does all the floating-point calculations at compile time, so the program succeeds.

The C99 standard, [ISO/IEC 9899](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf), says

> The values of floating operands and the results of floating expressions may be represented in greater precision and range than that required by the type; the types are not changed thereby.

So the compiler is free to pass back an 80-bit value, as others have described.  However, the standard goes on to say:

> The cast and assignment operators are still required to perform their specified conversions.

This explains why specifically assigning to a `double` forces the value down to 64-bits and returning as `double` from a function does not.  That is quite surprising it to me.

However, it looks like [the C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) will actually make this less confusing by adding this text:

> If the return expression is evaluated in a floating-point format different from the return type, the expression is converted as if by assignment [which removes any extra range and precision] to the return type of the function and the resulting value is returned to the caller.

So this code is basically exercising unspecified behavior as to whether the value does get truncated or not at various points.

---

For me, on Ubuntu Precise, with `-m32`:

- `clang` passes
- `clang -O9` also passes
- `gcc`, assertion fails
- `gcc -O9` passes, because it also is eliminating the constant expressions
- `gcc -std=c99` fails
- `gcc -std=c1x` also fails (but it may work on a later gcc)
- `gcc -ffloat-store` passes, but seems to have the side-effect of constant elimination

I don't think this is a gcc bug because the standard allows this behavior but the clang behavior is nicer.

Comment: There is no UB in the conversion.

Comment: I just edited the problem using now an int with a value = 10
The assert should not raise !!

Comment: @R.. It is not undefined at the fp level.  However, the C standard says the compiler may use higher precision, or it may not.

Comment: Thanks poolie, I think that I got it!

Comment: `-ffloat-store` is a rather harmful option. It makes code much slower and more bloated, and *does not* fix the conformance issues; it only approximates the right behavior. `-fexcess-precision=standard` is the right option to fix things, but it's implied by `-std=c99` or `-std=c11`.

Comment: @poolie Another interesting set of options is `-msse2 -fpmaph=sse`. They make GCC generate SSE2 floating-point instructions.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to all the details explained in other answers, I would say that there is a very simple rule concerning use of floating point types in almost any programming language since Fortran: **never check floating point values for precise equality**. All the knowledge about 80-bit and 64-bit values is true, but it is true for a certain hardware and a certain compiler (yes, if you change the compiler or even turn the optimizations on or off, something may change). The more general rule (applicable to **any code that is intended to be portable**) is that floating point values generally are not like integers or sequences of bytes, and can be changed, e.g. when copied, and checking them for equality often has unpredictable results.

So, even if it works in a test, usually it is better not to do so. It may fail later when something changes.

**UPD:** Though some people have downvoted, I insist the recommendation is generally correct. Things that seem to be just copying a value (they look so from a high level programming language programmer point of view; what happens in the initial example is a typical example, the value is returned and put into a variable and -- voila -- it is changed!), MAY change floating point values. Comparing floating point values for equality or inequality is often a bad practice that may be allowed ONLY if you know why you may do that in your certain case. And writing portable programs usually requires to minimize low-level knowledge. Yes, it is very unlikely that integer values like 0 or 1 are changed when put into a floating point variable or copied. But more complex values (in the example above we see what happens to a result of a simple arithmetic expression!) may.

Comment: +1: In my opinion the most sensible answer. I was not aware of the second point you mentioned (change on copy) - Thanks!

Comment: -1 for perpetuating FUD about floating point. There are plenty of places where you can compare floating point values for exact equality. For example, **all** numbers in Lua are floating point, but nobody would say you should never use the equality operator. The claim that copying can change values is generally false unless you intend for it to be interpreted in some strange way.

Comment: @R.., maybe for Lua it is fine, any rule **has exceptions**. But it is a **general rule**, you may break it **only** if you know exactly that no problem can happen in certain case (if you know that for Lua, of course you may compare floats for equality). In 99% of situations it is **not FUD**. And **for C/C++ the rule is always true**, and **any** portable code should think so, otherwise it stops to be portable. BTW, that's exactly what the example given in the initial question shows.

Comment: And finally, what I said is "there is a very simple rule concerning use of floating point types in **almost any** programming language since Fortran". So where is FUD? Just naked truth. :-) It is better to be aware of a common problem that really exists, than to live without knowing about it.

Comment: @Ellioh: Floating point in Lua behaves *exactly* the same as floating point in C. Here is a clear example of exact floating point usage: `for (double x=0; x<100; x++) { if (fmod(x,3)==1) ... }` and it may be desirable to use this form rather than an integer variable `x` if `x` is going to be used exclusively in floating-point expressions, so as to keep it in a floating-point register rather than converting it over and over.

Comment: Obviously copying them doesn't change the value at the machine level.  But this bug is a great example that unless you have a pretty detailed knowledge of exactly how your compiler interprets which particular version of the standard, they may be mutated by what is conceptually a copy operation, such as assigning a function return value to a variable of the same type.

Comment: @poolie, fully agree. Concerning copying. Returning a value and assigning it to a variable is (or may be) copying when viewed from a high-level programming language programmer's point of view. It seems very unlikely that just assigning a value to a new variable may change the value. But in fact no one knows what kind of storage is used for that variable. So, copying a value from FPU register to memory may have rather unpredictable results (though usually not for the values that are integer). And in portable code the knowledge about such stuff should be minimized, if not eliminated at all.