# What does the second part in usual arithmetic conversions in C11 standard mean?

Tags: c, floating-point, type-conversion, language-lawyer

In C11 standard

> 6.3.1.8  Usual arithmetic conversions
>
> 1 Many operators that expect operands of arithmetic type cause conversions and yield result
> types in a similar way. The purpose is to determine a common real type for the operands
> and result. For the speci?ed operands, each operand is converted, without change of type
> domain,  to  a  type  whose  corresponding  real  type  is  the  common  real  type. Unless
> explicitly stated otherwise, the common real type is also the corresponding real type of
> the result, whose type domain is the type domain of the operands if they are the same,
> and complex otherwise.  This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions: ...
>
> 2 The  values  of  ﬂoating  operands  and  of  the  results  of  ﬂoating  expressions  may  be
> represented in greater range and precision than that required by **the type**; the types are not
> changed thereby.

- What does point 2 mean?
- What is "the type"?
- What is "that required by the type"?

Can you give some examples, as well as word descriptions?

Comment: It means that if you declare something to be `float`, it's allowed to use `double` instead.

Comment: [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16888811/918959)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is referring to the type of the expression in question.

If you were to multiply two values of type `float`, the operands retain their type and the result has type float.  However, the implementation may chose to internally use a larger type to perform the operation and convert the result to the smaller type.

Some processors have a particular "natural" size for floating point operations that it is optimized to run faster on.  So if `float` happens to be smaller than that natural type then the compiled code may first convert the operands to that size so that the code runs faster.

Comment: Re “perform the operation and convert the result to the smaller type”: That is not a problem for the elementary operators with the formats commonly used for `float` and `double`; performing addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division of two `float` numbers using `double` and converting the result to `float` will always produce the same result as performing the operation using `float` (per Samuel A. Figueroa del Cid”s *A Rigorous Framework…* thesis). Problems arise in chains of calculations, when the `double` result is used in further operations.

Comment: The implementation may even choose to use internal representations for which it does not provide a corresponding data type, such as the 80-bit floating point representation of an x87 FPU. (Not that an implementation couldn't provide a data type corresponding to that representation, but at least some relevant implementations do not, or have not always done.)

Answer (score 4):

Floating point intermediate calculations may occur using "higher" types.

```
float a,b,c;
...
float d = a*b + c;
```

The product `a*b` *might* use `double` or `long double` math as well as the following addition.

This could result in a different value for `d` than using `float` only.

Method is reflected in `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`.

> The use of evaluation formats is characterized by the implementation-defined value of
> `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`  C17dr § 5.2.4.2.2 9.

> -1 indeterminable;
> 0 evaluate all operations and constants just to the range and precision of the type;
> 1 evaluate operations and constants of type `float` and `double` to the range and precision of the `double type`, evaluate `long double` operations and constants to the range and precision of the long double type;
> 2 evaluate all operations and constants to the range and precision of the `long double` type.

Comment: Note that this even applies to "intermediate values" that are stored in named variables of a specific type -- the compiler may use the higher precision value for computations that use that named value.